# Composite Primary Key in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a User table and a Question table. From that I have created by Answer table as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TYK_ANSWER")
public class Answer {

@EmbeddedId
UserQuestionPk userQuestionPk;

String answer;

int marks;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class UserQuestionPk implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

User user;
Question question;

//No getters and setters used here

}
```

But I'm getting a error

**Could not determine type for: model.Question, at table: TYK_ANSWER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(question)]**

**UPDATE**

While googling I observed this error is due to annotations sometimes used on getters and sometimes on variables. However in this case, all annotations are used on variables.

Comment: Do you have User and Question classes marked with @Entity?

Comment: @Koitoer yup I do have that...